# Loop over values in div and assign variable if exists - Python3 & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling to resolve a bug in a web scraper I've built in Python3 using BeautifulSoup. The element I'm targeting is: `flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs`and if that element exists it will contain upto 3 `flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs` but sometimes there may only be 1 or 2 or 3.

My code looks like this: -

```py
        product_effects = product.find_all('div', class_ = 'flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs')
        for i in range(len(product_effects)):
            product_effect1 = product_effects[0].text
            product_effect2 = product_effects[1].text
            product_effect3 = product_effects[2].text
```

The output looks great until it meets a result that has less than 3 effects which is where it breaks and the output throws the following error:-

```
    product_effect2 = product_effects[1].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a clean way to check if the initial `flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs` exists, if no -> assign 'Unknown' to product_effect1;2&3 but if yes count how many and assign accordingly.
So in the event of 1 feeling, product_effect1 would be captured but 2 & 3 would capture as 'Unknown' and continue? There can only be a maximum of 3 which is why my thought process was to just assign these statically.

Thanks in advance for any help! Any guidance notes, best practices would be super appreciated even if they don't come with example code! This is a passion project for me so I'm just trying to learn more than push a product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try and except.
This will assign in your case
`product_effect2 to product_effects[0].text`

If it reaches `product_effect2 = product_effects[1].text` and an error is thrown it will accept that. Then you'd probably want to break out of your for loop since
`product_effect2 to product_effects[2].text` will obviously not work.

```
product_effects = product.find_all('div', class_ = 'flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs')
for i in range(len(product_effects)):
    try:
        product_effect1 = product_effects[0].text
    except IndexError:pass
    try:
        product_effect1 = product_effects[1].text
    except IndexError:pass
    try:
        product_effect1 = product_effects[2].text
    except IndexError:pass
```

Umm, a better idea could be to try and except in the for loop using i as the number.

```
product_effects = product.find_all('div', class_ = 'flex items-center mr-sm mb-xs')
for i in range(len(product_effects)):
    try:
        product_effect1 = product_effects[i].text
    except IndexError:pass
```

Though I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how this functionality works in implementation? It appears to pass the error but now product_effect2 & product_effect3 pull through the values from the previous item rather than display as 'Unknown'? Products without any effects pull through all 3 effects from the previously item?

Comment: you need to handle assigning to effect2,3 so last idea won't work. Also, for both you would need to handle the OPs alternate assignment in the except. You could set the return of select() or find_all into a variable and test the len() as OP has then you will know which indices need populating with default value.